# JQuery nested list filter - Show all children when parent is a match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, filter

I have this jQuery function where it filters a list based on the label text vs a textbox input.

It needs to function in two different ways based on the type of match:

1. If a child is a match, show the parent. That's working.
2. If a parent is a match, show all the children. That's not working.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xtLwnshd/

```js
var labels = $('label');  // cache this for better performance

$('#filter').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  
  if (valThis == "") {
    labels.parent().show();          // show all lis
  } else {
    labels.each(function() {
      var label = $(this);                    // cache this
      var text = label.text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1) {
        label.parents('li').show()           // show all li parents up the ancestor tree
      } else {
       label.parent().hide();                // hide current li as it doesn't match
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<span class="checkbox-list">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Parent1</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Child12</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Child3</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item5</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item6</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item7</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item8</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</span>
```

How can I get this to work for #2 as well?  I tried showing all the children on any match but I think it is canceling itself out or something.  I'm not very good with JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We required the same functionality and after hours of search I decided to write my own function.

This is how it works:

- The first loop performs the search and sets the display property for each item according to wether or not a match was found. The function remembers matches by pushing them into the `matches` list.
- The second loop iterates over each match and checks if all of a match's children are hidden, which in turn means that only the parent was a match.
- If all children are hidden, the parent is the match and we want to let all of its items reappear.

It could use highlighting hits, but that's for another day.

```js
function filter(inputSelector, dataSelector) {
  let input = document.getElementById(inputSelector);
  let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  let ul = document.getElementById(dataSelector);
  let items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Treffer merken
  let matches = [];

  // Suchlauf: Treffer ermitteln, DOM-Elemente zeigen/verstecken
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    currentItem = items[i];

    txtValue = currentItem.textContent || currentItem.innerText || '';

    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      currentItem.style.display = '';
      matches.push(currentItem);
    } else {
      currentItem.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  // Trefferlauf: Alle getroffenen Elemente ablaufen und deren Kinder prüfen
  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    let childListItemsOfMatch = matches[i].getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Ermitteln, ob der Treffer ggf. bei einem Kind lag
    let allChildrenInvisible = true;
    for (let k = 0; k < childListItemsOfMatch.length; k++) {
      if (childListItemsOfMatch[k].style.display == '') {
        allChildrenInvisible = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Treffer lag beim Parent, also alle Kinder anzeigen
    if (allChildrenInvisible) {
      for (let k = 0; k < childListItemsOfMatch.length; k++) {
        childListItemsOfMatch[k].style.display = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Liste mit Filter</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Entwurfsmuster</h1>
    <p>Beispielsuchen: 'er', 'gof', 'method', 'lorem'/'ipsum'/'dolar', 'Erzeugungsmuster'</p>
    <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Suchbegriff eingeben..." onkeyup="filter('filter', 'data')">
    <ul id="data">
      <li>
        <h2>Erzeugungsmuster</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Abstract Factory (GoF)</li>
          <li>Builder (GoF)</li>
          <li>Factory Method (GoF)</li>
          <li>Multiton</li>
          <li>Object Pool</li>
          <li>Prototype (GoF)</li>
          <li>Singleton (GoF)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Strukturmuster</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Adapter (GoF)</li>
          <li>Bridge (GoF)</li>
          <li>Composite (GoF)</li>
          <li>Decorator (GoF)</li>
          <li>Fassade (GoF)</li>
          <li>Flyweight (GoF)</li>
          <li>Proxy (GoF)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Verhaltensmuster</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Chain of Responsibility (GoF)</li>
          <li>Command (GoF)</li>
          <li>Interceptor</li>
          <li>Interpreter (GoF)</li>
          <li>Iterator (GoF)</li>
          <li>Mediator (GoF)</li>
          <li>Memento (GoF)</li>
          <li>Null Object</li>
          <li>Observer (GoF)</li>
          <li>Protocol Stack</li>
          <li>State (GoF)</li>
          <li>Strategy (GoF)</li>
          <li>Template Method (GoF)</li>
          <li>Visitor (GoF)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Andere Muster</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Business Delegate</li>
          <li>Data Access Object</li>
          <li>Dependency Injection</li>
          <li>Extension Interface</li>
          <li>Fluent Interface</li>
          <li>Inversion of Control (IoC)</li>
          <li>Model View Controller (MVC)</li>
          <li>Model View Presenter (MVP)</li>
          <li>Model View Update (MVU)</li>
          <li>Model View ViewModel (MVVM)</li>
          <li>Registry</li>
          <li>Repository</li>
          <li>Service Locator</li>
          <li>Threadpool</li>
          <li>Transferobjekt</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem
        <ul>
          <li>ipsum
            <ul>
              <li>dolor</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```